# Which Node.js project uses a given dependency?

Tags: node.js, dependencies

I have a folder that contains all my cloned GitHub repositories. Now I would like to get a list of all the repositories that reference a given dependency.

I think of something such as:

```
$ whouses async
```

And then I'd like to get a list of all repositories, where async is either referenced as a dependency or a devDependency. Basically, all `whouses` would need to do is to enter each sub-folder of the current folder and check the package.json file.

Is there a tool available that does this, or am I better off writing one for myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there's a way to browse the npm registry for all published modules that depend on a library: https://npmjs.org/browse/depended/async. That may help you a bit. For a local set of modules I don't know off the top of my head if anything exists already or not.

Comment: Thanks for the hint :-). As we need it locally, we have now solved it with a small Node.js command-line script that scans package.json files.